# CSS :nth-child - extra spacing at bottom

Tags: css, css-selectors

Page in question: http://bit.ly/1xLOmeS

Every third LI has extra spacing at bottom that isn't supposed to be there.
I've tried using nth-child (odd) and (even) as shown below, and have also tried just the li:nth-child(2n+2) condition with the right margin set to 0px to prevent every 2nd box being shifted to the next line. Where is this space coming from??

CSS

```
ul.comment-card {
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.comment-card li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px 26px 0;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 327px;
}
.comment-card li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 26px 0;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 327px;
}
.comment-card li .meta {
    color: #767da1;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
.comment-card .meta img {
    position: relative; 
    top: -8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.comment-card li:nth-child(odd) {
background: #fff;
display: inline-block;    
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 20px 26px 0;
padding: 30px;
width: 327px;
}
.comment-card li:nth-child(even) {
background: #fff;
display: inline-block;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 26px 0;
padding: 30px;
width: 327px;
}
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jf9cc4n/)

Comment: I understand it goes against StackOverflow's rules and philosophy to just drop a piece of code (even if it works!) without further explanation. It is not constructive at all....

Comment: I was missing 'overflow: hidden;'